# Хотел сделать телеграм бота, выдает ошибку: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pycharm

Хотел сделать телеграм бота, начал писать приветствие, вроде всё норм, но после запуска выдалась ошибка: *Process finished with exit code 1*

**(Python, pycharm)**

В программировании недавно и никогда не хотел с ним связывать жизнь, просто очень нужен бот, не знаю что делать:(

Сам код:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler

def sms(bot, update):
    print('Кто-то отправил команду /start.')
    bot.message.reply_text("Привет! Я бот Equestria Cards. Тут мы собираем карточки с нашими любимыми персонажами! \nЧтоб получить карту напиши: \n/addcards")


def main():
    my_bot = Updater("6435301810:AAEZJtiI9oIE8n7PFWYQUJgFWdiHmLS-xqY", "https://telegg.ru/orig/bot", use_context=True)

    my_bot.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', sms))

    my_bot.start_polling()
    my_bot.idle()


main()


Текст ошибки:
"D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\MLP BOT.py" 
D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py:41: UserWarning: python-telegram-bot wasn't properly installed. Please refer to README.rst on how to properly install.
  warnings.warn("python-telegram-bot wasn't properly installed. Please refer to README.rst on "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\MLP BOT.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from .bot import Bot
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 43, in <module>
    from telegram.utils.request import Request
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 35, in <module>
    import telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3 as urllib3
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "D:\Pictures\ГОТОВЫЕ АРТЫ\1ПОНИ КАРТОЧКИ\CODE PONY\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 11, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Даутовы\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```